# Angularjs using directive and $setValidity to validate a dynamic group of dropdowns, can not get the error message to show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-repeat

i m working on a piece of code that generates multiple dropdowns with ng-repeat, then validate the dropdown so that the selected value can not be the same. so far, i've managed to setValidity with ngModelCtrl inside link function, but I can not get the error message to display. here's the code

HTML:

```
<fieldset ng-show="!item.periodic">

        <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(key,value) in tags_limit track by $index">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="attributes[{{key+1}}]">val {{key+1}}</label>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <select class="form-control attribute" name="attributes[{{key}}]" id="attributes[{{key+1}}]"
                        ng-options="attribute.id as attribute.name for attribute in documentAttributes | orderBy: 'name'"
                        ng-model="item.attributes[key]" unique-group>
                    <option value="">None</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <small class="help-block" ng-show="FORMNAME.attributes[key].$error.dupTags">Please change tag, tags can not repeat</small>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

unique-group dirctive js:

```
angular.module('indeksApp')
.directive('uniqueGroup', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:false,
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs,ngModelCtrl) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel,function(value){
                var tempArray=[];

                _.forEach(scope.$parent.item.attributes,function(val,key){
                    if (val === value)tempArray.push('key')
                });

                if(tempArray.length >1){
                    // is invalid
                    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('dupTags',false)
                }else{
                    // is valid
                    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('dupTags',true)
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

been stuck on this for a while now, any helps are much appreciated

Comment: it would be great if you can create a working demo of this someone will be able to help better.

Comment: Aren't ngModelControllers associated with the ng-model form fields exposed as properties of the surrounding form element FormController - rather than properties of the scope? here shouldn't ng-show="attributes[key].$error.dupTags" be ng-show="whateverYouNamedYourForm.attributes[key].$error.dupTags"

Comment: Hello @IAmDranged Yeah your right, thats a mistake i made when i pasted the code here, i will change it to FORMNAME.attributes[key].$error.dupTags, but even with the formname included, the error message dosn't show

Comment: Hello @Manish, ill see if i can create somthing in plunker, thanks for the advice